# Difference between【怠けものブラシ】and【怠惰なブラシ】？

Tags: particles, particle-の, particle-な

【怠けものブラシ】was the title of a brush i downloaded (for a drawing app).
【怠惰なブラシ】is what i was told is the "correct" way of putting the same phrase.

the first phrase is from a native speaker. is it sort of slang, or a joke i'm missing out on? for more context: the brush is sort of described as "the lazy brush you can use for everything!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

怠惰なブラシ sounds like a brush that is lazy. That is, a personified brush who has its own will and refuses to work hard.

怠けものブラシ may refer to the same thing depending on the context, but it usually refers to a brush suitable for use by lazy people. This name doesn't sound slangy or funny at all to me. [怠けもの](https://jisho.org/word/%E6%80%A0%E3%81%91%E8%80%85) is a compound noun meaning "lazy person", so the title simply means "lazy person('s) brush". If someone said this name is incorrect, you don't have to believe them.